# php functions playing games

Tags: php, function, scope, global

I'm curious as to why variables aren't echoing using a function... (If that makes sense lol..)

```
function name(){
   echo "$info->fullname";
}
```

When i then use

```
<?php name(); ?>
```

anywhere on withing the script, it's completely blank, yet if i remove the variable and put static text, it echo's out just fine...

It works fine without using it as a function, it echo's "Joe Bloggs"...

Not quite sure why it doesn't work ? lol

Any ideas guys?

Comment: The answer is `variable scope` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes MarkBaker is right. and you should use `global`. something like this.

```
function name(){
   global $info;

   echo $info->fullname;
}
```

or pass the variable to function like this.

```
function name($info){
   global $info;

   echo $info->fullname;
}
```

use

```
<?php name($info); ?>
```

and one advice **which is not important at all** : `"` is slower than `'` try to use `"` only if needed.

Comment: Thank you guys! Something i've never thought of doing until now. Great Help! Thanks again!

Comment: Don't recommend `global` as the solution.... pass $info as an argument to the function

Comment: And `"` isn't necessarily slower than `'`.... you'd be hard put to detect milliseconds saving over a day

Comment: @imsiso - It isn't a good idea to pollution the global space; global is bad practise... and $info may not even exist at global level if there are several nested levels of functions

Comment: I mean that your comment about `"` being slower than `'` is not correct, there is no difference between the two, although there is a popular myth that `'` is faster

Comment: There's a lot been written about `'` and `"` without any evidence that one is faster than the other... but even if you do test it, you'll not see any difference between the two

Comment: ok thank you so much I will try it and now I think lets delete spam comments before somebody flags them.